# Why is it not possible to install tomcat as a service on WinowsXP SP3?

Tags: tomcat

When I run the set up apache-tomcat-6.0.20.exe for WindowsXP I get the message from the Tomcat Setup as "Failed to install tomcat6 service check your settings and permissions".I have the permissions.The only thing I think that is different from the setup needs is the JRE version.But the tomcat-preconfigured-6.0.18.zip downloaded from coreservlets.com works fine with the J2SE 6 JRE.The setup always stops when the setup dialog box displays the message "using jvm:c:\program files\java\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll".There is no any other service or another version of Tomcat installed even as a service.

Then I tried the following!!!

I installed Tomcat using apache-tomcat-6.0.20.exe But not as a service.Then from the bin I tried to run "tomcat6.exe service runner" But it did not start the service log is as follows

```
[2009-07-21 20:02:34] [info] Procrun (2.0.4.0) started
[2009-07-21 20:02:34] [info] Service Tomcat6 name Apache Tomcat 6
[2009-07-21 20:02:35] [info] Service Tomcat6 installed
[2009-07-21 20:02:35] [info] Procrun finished.
[2009-07-21 21:46:10] [info] Procrun (2.0.4.0) started
[2009-07-21 21:46:10] [info] Debugging Service...
[2009-07-21 21:46:10] [info] Starting service...
[2009-07-21 21:46:10] [1030 prunsrv.c] [error] Failed setting process executable
[2009-07-21 21:46:10] [1269 prunsrv.c] [error] ServiceStart returned 2
[2009-07-21 21:46:10] [info] Debug service finished.
[2009-07-21 21:46:10] [info] Procrun finished.
[2009-07-21 21:46:14] [info] Procrun (2.0.4.0) started
[2009-07-21 21:46:14] [info] Debugging Service...
[2009-07-21 21:46:14] [info] Starting service...
[2009-07-21 21:46:14] [1030 prunsrv.c] [error] Failed setting process executable
[2009-07-21 21:46:14] [1269 prunsrv.c] [error] ServiceStart returned 2
[2009-07-21 21:46:14] [info] Debug service finished.
[2009-07-21 21:46:14] [info] Procrun finished.
[2009-07-21 21:46:24] [info] Procrun (2.0.4.0) started
[2009-07-21 21:46:24] [info] Running Service...
[2009-07-21 21:46:24] [info] Starting service...
[2009-07-21 21:46:24] [1030 prunsrv.c] [error] Failed setting process executable
[2009-07-21 21:46:24] [1269 prunsrv.c] [error] ServiceStart returned 2
[2009-07-21 21:46:24] [info] Run service finished.
[2009-07-21 21:46:24] [info] Procrun finished.
[2009-07-21 21:46:28] [info] Procrun (2.0.4.0) started
[2009-07-21 21:46:28] [info] Running Service...
[2009-07-21 21:46:28] [info] Starting service...
[2009-07-21 21:46:28] [1030 prunsrv.c] [error] Failed setting process executable
[2009-07-21 21:46:28] [1269 prunsrv.c] [error] ServiceStart returned 2
[2009-07-21 21:46:28] [info] Run service finished.
[2009-07-21 21:46:28] [info] Procrun finished.
[2009-07-21 21:46:31] [info] Procrun (2.0.4.0) started
[2009-07-21 21:46:31] [info] Running Service...
[2009-07-21 21:46:31] [info] Starting service...
[2009-07-21 21:46:32] [1030 prunsrv.c] [error] Failed setting process executable
[2009-07-21 21:46:32] [1269 prunsrv.c] [error] ServiceStart returned 2
[2009-07-21 21:46:32] [info] Run service finished.
[2009-07-21 21:46:32] [info] Procrun finished.
[2009-07-21 21:46:35] [info] Procrun (2.0.4.0) started
[2009-07-21 21:46:35] [info] Running Service...
[2009-07-21 21:46:35] [info] Starting service...
[2009-07-21 21:46:35] [1030 prunsrv.c] [error] Failed setting process executable
[2009-07-21 21:46:35] [1269 prunsrv.c] [error] ServiceStart returned 2
[2009-07-21 21:46:35] [info] Run service finished.
[2009-07-21 21:46:35] [info] Procrun finished.
[2009-07-21 21:53:44] [info] Procrun (2.0.4.0) started
[2009-07-21 21:53:44] [info] Debugging Service...
[2009-07-21 21:53:44] [info] Starting service...
[2009-07-21 21:53:44] [1030 prunsrv.c] [error] Failed setting process executable
[2009-07-21 21:53:44] [1269 prunsrv.c] [error] ServiceStart returned 2
[2009-07-21 21:53:44] [info] Debug service finished.
[2009-07-21 21:53:44] [info] Procrun finished.
[2009-07-21 21:54:06] [info] Procrun (2.0.4.0) started
[2009-07-21 21:54:06] [info] Debugging Service...
[2009-07-21 21:54:06] [info] Starting service...
[2009-07-21 21:54:06] [1030 prunsrv.c] [error] Failed setting process executable
[2009-07-21 21:54:06] [1269 prunsrv.c] [error] ServiceStart returned 2
[2009-07-21 21:54:06] [info] Debug service finished.
[2009-07-21 21:54:06] [info] Procrun finished.
[2009-07-21 21:55:44] [info] Procrun (2.0.4.0) started
[2009-07-21 21:55:44] [info] Debugging Service...
[2009-07-21 21:55:44] [info] Starting service...
[2009-07-21 21:55:44] [1030 prunsrv.c] [error] Failed setting process executable
[2009-07-21 21:55:44] [1269 prunsrv.c] [error] ServiceStart returned 2
[2009-07-21 21:55:44] [info] Debug service finished.
[2009-07-21 21:55:44] [info] Procrun finished.
[2009-07-21 21:55:44] [info] Procrun (2.0.4.0) started
[2009-07-21 21:55:44] [info] Debugging Service...
[2009-07-21 21:55:44] [info] Starting service...
[2009-07-21 21:55:44] [1030 prunsrv.c] [error] Failed setting process executable
[2009-07-21 21:55:44] [1269 prunsrv.c] [error] ServiceStart returned 2
[2009-07-21 21:55:44] [info] Debug service finished.
[2009-07-21 21:55:44] [info] Procrun finished.
[2009-07-21 21:55:45] [info] Procrun (2.0.4.0) started
[2009-07-21 21:55:45] [info] Debugging Service...
[2009-07-21 21:55:45] [info] Starting service...
[2009-07-21 21:55:45] [1030 prunsrv.c] [error] Failed setting process executable
[2009-07-21 21:55:45] [1269 prunsrv.c] [error] ServiceStart returned 2
[2009-07-21 21:55:45] [info] Debug service finished.
[2009-07-21 21:55:45] [info] Procrun finished.
```

Your ideas please!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: The home version of WindowsXP does not have IIS that **may** be related to your problems.  I don't know if tomcat depends on IIS in anyway.

Answer (score 1):

my installation based on Windows Server 2003 SP2 and Tomcat 7. I think the problem is the same like the installation on windows xp.

First try to change the variable values. The default System Variable value is %SystemRoot%\TEMP and the default User Variable value is %USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temp. Change the values for TEMP and TMP in User variables and in System variables from the defaults to C:\temp.

(Right click on "My Computer", go to Properties. Look under Startup and Recovery and press the Environment Variables button)

If you have furthermore Problems with Tomcat Installation try the solution below from Søren Løvborg, this one works for me. To install later the Service Monitor just start the Setup and ignore the errors. Afterwards i have a working installation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if related to the problem above, but I got the same errors after simply installing the Tomcat service using

```
tomcat6 //IS//
```

Problem is that this doesn't configure the necessary settings.

To fix this, first remove the service again, if installed:

```
tomcat6 //DS//
```

Then install using

```
service.bat install
```

More information: [Apache Tomcat 6.0 Windows service HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html)